# How to define correct shape for tf-agents in batch learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, tensor

I am trying to train a DDPG agent with batch learning using the tf_agents library. However I require to define an observation_spec and action_spec which state the shapes of the tensors the agent would receive. I have managed to create the trajectories with which I can feed the data however these trajectories and the agent itself have mismatched shapes

I have tried changing the observation and action specs with the agent definition. This is my agent defintion:

```py
observation_spec = TensorSpec(shape = (1,),dtype =  tf.float32)
time_step_spec = time_step.time_step_spec(observation_spec)
action_spec = BoundedTensorSpec([1],tf.float32,minimum = -100, maximum = 100)
actor_network = ActorNetwork(
        input_tensor_spec=observation_spec,
        output_tensor_spec=action_spec,
        fc_layer_params=(100,200,100),
        name="ddpg_ActorNetwork"
    )
critic_net_input_specs = (observation_spec, action_spec)
critic_network = CriticNetwork(
    input_tensor_spec=critic_net_input_specs,
    observation_fc_layer_params=(200,100),
    joint_fc_layer_params=(100,200),
    action_fc_layer_params=None,
    name="ddpg_CriticNetwork"
)



agent = ddpg_agent.DdpgAgent(
    time_step_spec=time_step_spec,
    action_spec=action_spec,
    actor_network=actor_network,
    critic_network=critic_network,
    actor_optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    critic_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
)
```

This is what the trajectory looks like

```py
Trajectory(step_type=<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=int32, numpy=array([[0, 1]], dtype=int32)>, observation=<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=int32, numpy=array([[280, 280]], dtype=int32)>, action=<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float64, numpy=array([[nan,  0.]])>, policy_info=(), next_step_type=<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=int32, numpy=array([[1, 1]], dtype=int32)>, reward=<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float64, numpy=array([[ -6.93147181, -12.14113521]])>, discount=<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.9, 0.9]], dtype=float32)>)
```

i should be able to call agent.train(trajectory) and it would work however I get the following error:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-325-bf162a5dc8d7> in <module>
----> 1 agent.train(trajs[0])

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_agents/agents/tf_agent.py in train(self, experience, weights)
    213           "experience must be type Trajectory, saw type: %s" % type(experience))
    214 
--> 215     self._check_trajectory_dimensions(experience)
    216 
    217     if self._enable_functions:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_agents/agents/tf_agent.py in _check_trajectory_dimensions(self, experience)
    137     if not nest_utils.is_batched_nested_tensors(
    138         experience, self.collect_data_spec,
--> 139         num_outer_dims=self._num_outer_dims):
    140       debug_str_1 = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda tp: tp.shape, experience)
    141       debug_str_2 = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda spec: spec.shape,

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_agents/utils/nest_utils.py in is_batched_nested_tensors(tensors, specs, num_outer_dims)
    142       'And spec_shapes:\n   %s' %
    143       (num_outer_dims, tf.nest.pack_sequence_as(tensors, tensor_shapes),
--> 144        tf.nest.pack_sequence_as(specs, spec_shapes)))
    145 
    146 

ValueError: Received a mix of batched and unbatched Tensors, or Tensors are not compatible with Specs.  num_outer_dims: 2.
Saw tensor_shapes:
   Trajectory(step_type=TensorShape([1, 2]), observation=TensorShape([1, 2]), action=TensorShape([1, 2]), policy_info=(), next_step_type=TensorShape([1, 2]), reward=TensorShape([1, 2]), discount=TensorShape([1, 2]))
And spec_shapes:
   Trajectory(step_type=TensorShape([]), observation=TensorShape([1]), action=TensorShape([1]), policy_info=(), next_step_type=TensorShape([]), reward=TensorShape([]), discount=TensorShape([]))
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm trying to get a DQN agent to work, and I'm getting the same issue. Did you by any chance manage to find a solution for it? This is the error I'm getting.


ValueError: Received a mix of batched and unbatched Tensors, or Tensors are not compatible with Specs.  num_outer_dims: 0.
Saw tensor_shapes:
   TimeStep(step_type=TensorShape([]), reward=TensorShape([]), discount=TensorShape([]), observation=TensorShape([4, 4]))
And spec_shapes:
   TimeStep(step_type=TensorShape([]), reward=TensorShape([]), discount=TensorShape([]), observation=TensorShape([4]))

Comment: @IbraheemNofal That is pretty much the same thing. I dont know how for DQN but I raised a github issue for DDPG and a contributor told me what shape the DDPG accepts. working back from this I was able to change the shapes of the data spec for my replay buffer. This got the DDPG training but it doesnt converge. 
If you are interested:
https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/issues/236

Comment: Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved by using the environment. In TF-Agents the environment needs to follow the `PyEnvironment` class (and then you wrap this with a `TFPyEnvironment` for parallel execution of multiple envs). If you have already defined your environment to match this class' specification then your environment should already provide you with the two methods `env.time_step_spec()` and `env.action_spec()`. Simply feed these two to your agent and you should be done.

It becomes a bit more complicated if you want to have multiple outputs from your environment that don't all go into your agent. In this case you will need to define an `observation_and_action_constraint_splitter` fuction to pass to your agent. For more details as to how to get your TensorSpecs/ArraySpecs right, and for an example of something that works see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264602/12812985)