# Defining TF-Agents action in py_environment.PyEnvironment Class

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

So I'm trying to define the action_spec in the py_environment.PyEnvironment Class for a DQN network using TF-Agents. Is action limited to returning integer values? I have read through a few online tutorials and in every case it was for a simple game, like chess or tic tac toe. Where you only needed to define a single integer in a small space to make a move/action.

For my use case, action needs to define sets of coordinates in two dimensional space. To make it more complicated, I want the agent too not only choose the X, Y coordinates but also the number of [X, Y] sets.

I need action to return a list of lists. Something like this:

```
action = [[100, 200], [300, 350], [550, 876]]
```

With this in mind; I'm not entirely sure how to define action_spec.

I saw  this thread here: [tf_agents custom time_step_spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348203/tf-agents-custom-time-step-spec/65264602#65264602)

Where it shows the use of a dictionary of ArraySpecs(). Is that what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

SO according to this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/issues/329

DQN for TF-Agents only supports a single action. As in the dimensions of the action_spec cannot be larger than `shape(1,)`. Keep this in mind before using TF-Agents.